# Performance issue with Projection

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I've got a problem with projection in hibernate, it takes forever to finish a simple query.
My dao method:

> ```
> @Override  
> @Transactional  
> public List<String> getSourcePaths(List<Integer> sourceIds) {  
>     @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  
>     List<String> list = getSession()  
>          .createCriteria(AnaFileDB.class)
>          .setProjection(Projections.property("sourcePath"))
>          .add(Restrictions.in("source.id", sourceIds))
>          .list();
>
>     return list;
> }
> ```

The AnaFileDB class is like this:

> ```
> @Entity
> @Table(name = "ANA_FILE")
> public class AnaFileDB {
> ...
> private String sourcePath;
> private AnaFileSourceDB source;
> ...
> }
> ```

Logs:

> 2014-01-15 17:31:36,227 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open PreparedStatement (open PreparedStatements: 0, globally: 0)
>   Hibernate:
>       /* criteria query */ select
>           this_.FILE_SOURCE_PATH as y0_
>       from
>          ANA_FILE this_
>      where
>          this_.FILE_SOURCE_ID in (
>              ?
>          )
>    2014-01-15 17:31:36,227 [http-8080-5] TRACE org.hibernate.type.IntegerType - binding '2' to parameter: 1
>   2014-01-15 18:17:43,569 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher - about to open ResultSet (open ResultSets: 0, globally: 0)
>   2014-01-15 18:17:43,569 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result row:
>   2014-01-15 18:17:43,569 [http-8080-5] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - returning '2013.03.01_Tom Januario/01_CTG1203401_CTG.csv' as column: y0_
>   2014-01-15 18:17:43,570 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result row:
>   2014-01-15 18:17:43,570 [http-8080-5] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - returning '2013.03.01_Tom Januario/02_CTG2203539_CTG.csv' as column: y0_
>   2014-01-15 18:17:43,570 [http-8080-5] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result row:
>   2014-01-15 18:17:43,570 [http-8080-5] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - returning '2013.03.01_Tom Januario/03_CTG3203718_CTG.csv' as column: y0_

And as there's a lot of rows (tens of thousands), I got a heck of a log files like this

> 2014-01-15 17:13:40,462 [http-8080-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader - result row:
>   2014-01-15 17:13:40,462 [http-8080-1] TRACE org.hibernate.type.StringType - returning 'project2/screen4/run4/CTG/CSI000000447_CTG.csv' as column: y0_

How to solve it?

Comment: What is hibernate specific about it?  Is loading "tens of thousands" of rows significantly faster with just JDBC?

Answer (score 0):

If your table having tons of records then `IN` will take long time to execute.Try to `EXPLAIN` the query and add `INDEX` on that table may be you will get some boost up.

**UPDATE**

You can try in this way:

```
Disjunction orConditions = Restrctions.disjunction();
orConditions.add(Restrictions.in("source.id", sourceIds));

List<String> list = session.createCriteria(AnaFileDB.class)
                   .add(orConditions)
                   .list();
```

Comment: The problem is that when I use the sql query returned by hibernate log in, for example, Sql Developer there's no problem with efficiency, only hibernate is quite slow in this case. From logs it seems like hibernate got data quite quickly but it quite slow when retrieving data from ResultSet (that's my guess).

Comment: First try to `EXPLAIN` the query and `INDEX` on that column otherwise you can pass `id` using an `for loop` but this is another overhead where tons of `select` query get fired on DB

Comment: By the updated code in answer i don't think query ll get change, Is it @Alinoe ?

Comment: I tried even .add(Restrictions.eq("source.id", 2) and nothing changed. As I said, I think it's not problem with query produced by Hibernate but with data retrieving from ResultSet. You can see example in my post like StringType - returning 'dir/subdir/file_name.csv' and I see hundreds of such log statements (one by file of course), I think it means that data are fetched but there's some problem with creating list of Strings from resultset.

Comment: okey,by keeping `.add(Restrictions.eq("source.id", 2)` can you put your logger to `ERROR` level, may be u are missing some error as u said there is hundreds of such log statement.

Comment: As you can see in the listing error level is set to DEBUG (for org.hibernate) and ALL (for org.hibernate.type)